# What is the word for selling something back to the seller?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any English word for the action of selling something back to the one you bought it from? For example when you buy a second hand car from a car dealer and a year later you sell it back to them. From your perspective it can be (not exactly) "resell", but what can it be from the dealer's perspective (I don't think "rebuy" is a word).

Comment: Hi @megatron please confirm whether you are looking for verbs for the seller's repurchase of an item, or vice versa. The question title asks for words describing the act of 'selling something back to the seller'. Many thanks.

Comment: I was looking for words for both ways. I'm a bit more interested in the action from my perspective (selling back), but I also want to know the word for the other side's perspective. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

*Repurchase* is used [far more often](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=repurchase%2Crebuy&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crepurchase%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crebuy%3B%2Cc0) than rebuy.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuy would actually be seem to be the correct word.

It is listed in the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/159316?redirectedFrom=rebuy&):

> 1. trans. To buy back. Also intr.

With sources dating back to 1611. Neither is the entry marked as obsolete or rare in any fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[reacquisition](http://the%20fact%20or%20process%20of%20acquiring%20something%20again)*

> the fact or process of acquiring something again

*Collins*